# raise ConnectionError in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

i want to raise `ConnectionError` ([a python 3 subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError)) when my program fails to  connect to a local service. i'm using python2.7. testing this out though, it looks like i have to import a module to get this working:

```
>>> raise ConnectionError("test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ConnectionError' is not defined
```

how can i raise this type of exception?

Comment: Are you using Python 3?  The documentation you linked to is for Python 3, and in Python 3 your code works.

Comment: nope python2.7. i will update the op

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to link to Python 3 documentation if your question is about Python 2.

Comment: i thought there might be a way to import the python 3 module. something like `from future import *`

Comment: Just define your own ConnectionError exception. See the section on [User-defined Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) in the official Python docs for details.

Comment: This is an entirely reasonable question. Whichever ignoramus downvoted it has done a disservice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ConnectionError does not exist in Python 2, as you can see from [the Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).  You can of course create your own subclass of OSError (and even call it ConnectionError if you want), but no such thing is built in.